# Calculate the difference in start and end times of different steps in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have a df like this

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
MEASUREMENT <- c("Length","Length","Length","Length","Width","Width","Width","Width","Length","Length","Length","Length","Width","Width","Width","Width") 
Step <- c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4")    
StartDatetime <- c("2015-09-29 00:00:13","2015-09-29 00:02:13","2015-09-29 00:04:13","2015-09-29 00:06:16","2015-09-29 00:07:12","2015-09-29 00:10:13","2015-09-29 00:10:23","2015-09-29 00:12:15","2015-09-29 00:14:13","2015-09-29 00:16:13","2015-09-29 00:19:14","2015-09-29 00:20:13","2015-09-29 00:24:13","2015-09-29 00:26:19","2015-09-29 00:27:20","2015-09-29 00:29:13")    
EndDatetime <- c("2015-09-29 00:01:13","2015-09-29 00:03:13","2015-09-29 00:05:23","2015-09-29 00:07:11","2015-09-29 00:08:12","2015-09-29 00:10:23","2015-09-29 00:11:13","2015-09-29 00:13:13","2015-09-29 00:15:13","2015-09-29 00:17:19","2015-09-29 00:20:13","2015-09-29 00:22:13","2015-09-29 00:26:13","2015-09-29 00:27:13","2015-09-29 00:28:13","2015-09-29 00:32:13")

df1 <- data.frame(ID,MEASUREMENT,Step,StartDatetime,EndDatetime)
df1$StartDatetime <- as.POSIXct(df1$StartDatetime)
df1$EndDatetime <- as.POSIXct(df1$EndDatetime)
```

I am trying to calculate the elapsed time (secs) between steps grouped by ID & Measurement

```
If Step = 1 then the elapsed time = 0
If Step = 2 then elapsed time = StartDatetime (Step 2) - EndDatetime (Step 1)
```

The above logic applies for Step = 3 & 4 as well.

My **desired output** is

```
    ID MEASUREMENT Step       StartDatetime         EndDatetime ElapsedTime
    A      Length    1 2015-09-29 00:00:13 2015-09-29 00:01:13           0
    A      Length    2 2015-09-29 00:02:13 2015-09-29 00:03:13          60
    A      Length    3 2015-09-29 00:04:13 2015-09-29 00:05:23          60
    A      Length    4 2015-09-29 00:06:16 2015-09-29 00:07:11          53
    A       Width    1 2015-09-29 00:07:12 2015-09-29 00:08:12           0
    A       Width    2 2015-09-29 00:10:13 2015-09-29 00:10:23         121
    A       Width    3 2015-09-29 00:10:23 2015-09-29 00:11:13           0
    A       Width    4 2015-09-29 00:12:15 2015-09-29 00:13:13          62
    B      Length    1 2015-09-29 00:14:13 2015-09-29 00:15:13           0
    B      Length    2 2015-09-29 00:16:13 2015-09-29 00:17:19          60
    B      Length    3 2015-09-29 00:19:14 2015-09-29 00:20:13         115
    B      Length    4 2015-09-29 00:20:13 2015-09-29 00:22:13           0
    B       Width    1 2015-09-29 00:24:13 2015-09-29 00:26:13           0
    B       Width    2 2015-09-29 00:26:19 2015-09-29 00:27:13           6
    B       Width    3 2015-09-29 00:27:20 2015-09-29 00:28:13           7
    B       Width    4 2015-09-29 00:29:13 2015-09-29 00:32:13          60
```

I am trying it this way but not getting it right

```
library(plyr)
df <- ddply(df1, .(ID,MEASUREMENT,Step),
            summarize,
            ElapsedTime=as.numeric(difftime(df1$StartDatetime, df1$EndDatetime, 
                                            units = "secs")))
```

How do I accomplish my desired output? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some `tidyverse` functions.  First you `group_by` the columns that you're interested in. Then with `mutate` you can add another column with elapsed time calculated with a `lag` (default lag of 1) which will essentially give you the value of the previous EndDatetime.  Last, since the lag will default to NA, we set all NA to zero like in your example with `replace_na`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID,MEASUREMENT) %>% 
  mutate(ElapsedTime = StartDatetime - lag(EndDatetime)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(ElapsedTime =0))
# A tibble: 16 x 6
# Groups: ID, MEASUREMENT [4]
#   ID    MEASUREMENT Step  StartDatetime       EndDatetime         ElapsedTime
#   <fct> <fct>       <fct> <dttm>              <dttm>              <time>     
# 1 A     Length      1     2015-09-29 00:00:13 2015-09-29 00:01:13 0          
# 2 A     Length      2     2015-09-29 00:02:13 2015-09-29 00:03:13 60         
# 3 A     Length      3     2015-09-29 00:04:13 2015-09-29 00:05:23 60         
# 4 A     Length      4     2015-09-29 00:06:16 2015-09-29 00:07:11 53         
# 5 A     Width       1     2015-09-29 00:07:12 2015-09-29 00:08:12 0          
# 6 A     Width       2     2015-09-29 00:10:13 2015-09-29 00:10:23 121        
# 7 A     Width       3     2015-09-29 00:10:23 2015-09-29 00:11:13 0          
# 8 A     Width       4     2015-09-29 00:12:15 2015-09-29 00:13:13 62         
# 9 B     Length      1     2015-09-29 00:14:13 2015-09-29 00:15:13 0          
#10 B     Length      2     2015-09-29 00:16:13 2015-09-29 00:17:19 60         
#11 B     Length      3     2015-09-29 00:19:14 2015-09-29 00:20:13 115        
#12 B     Length      4     2015-09-29 00:20:13 2015-09-29 00:22:13 0          
#13 B     Width       1     2015-09-29 00:24:13 2015-09-29 00:26:13 0          
#14 B     Width       2     2015-09-29 00:26:19 2015-09-29 00:27:13 6          
#15 B     Width       3     2015-09-29 00:27:20 2015-09-29 00:28:13 7          
#16 B     Width       4     2015-09-29 00:29:13 2015-09-29 00:32:13 60
```